# Why does it throws error like this?

Tags: asp.net

I do import the data from Excel sheet to Sql database..everything is fine,when i run this code,my access engine could not find mt sheet,it throws like this error..
my error is

> The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

but i already checked with my designation folder,its correct..then i don't know why it's repeated

my C# code below..

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    string constr = @"Data Source=VIS1-B12\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sql_Excel;Integrated Security=True providerName=System.Data.SqlClient" ;

    protected void btn_okClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Fup_Excel.PostedFile.FileName;
        string exconstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+path+";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

        OleDbConnection excelcon = new OleDbConnection(exconstr);
        excelcon.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", excelcon);
        OleDbDataReader dbreader;
        OleDbDataAdapter dap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //dap.Fill(ds,"sheet1");
        dbreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        SqlBulkCopy bcpy = new SqlBulkCopy(constr);
        bcpy.DestinationTableName = "Excel_Details";
        bcpy.WriteToServer(dbreader);
        //GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
        excelcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the *Excel* file and verify the names of sheet. And important thing is that you've to copy the uploaded file before you begin to read.

Comment: no i am checked with correct file only

Comment: i cant unserstand..can you make it clear much more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better you should retrieve excel sheet name using code.
Code is shown below

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
con.Open();
DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
```

Comment: this is also throws errors in line at dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords)